# Botan: serialize ECDH private key

Tags: c++, cryptography, botan

I created a new key pair using

```
  Botan::EC_Group ecgroup("brainpool512r1");
  Botan::ECDH_PrivateKey privKey(CBotanInitEx::RNG(), ecgroup);
```

(compared to RSA, that was fast!)

Trying to serialize it using PKCS#8, as per recommendations here: 
https://botan.randombit.net/manual/pubkey.html#serializing-public-keys

```
  datPubKey  = Botan::X509::BER_encode(privKey);
  txtPubKey  = Botan::X509::PEM_encode(privKey);

  datPrivKey = Botan::PKCS8::BER_encode(privKey, CBotanInitEx::RNG(), pwd);
  txtPrivKey = Botan::PKCS8::PEM_encode(privKey, CBotanInitEx::RNG(), pwd);
```

I get an exception:

```
PK algo ECDH has no defined OIDs
```

even though botan initialization does pass this line:

```
add_oid(config, "1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.13", "brainpool512r1");
```

---

How do I serialize a ECDH_PrivateKey?

Comment: The OID of the curve is different from the OID of the key type. Why do you *need* to serialize a ECDH key? Static DH is not used that much. Or do you use it for ECDSA (different algorithm, same key type)?

Comment: Guess I need to read up what I'm actually doing - all the TLA..FLA's making my head spin. I'm coming from an existing RSA public key "example", where keys are serialized for exchange between the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

RSA - your previous algorithm - is used for authentication / signing, so I'd assume ECDSA here. In that case you should use `ECDSA_PrivateKey` instead of `ECDH_PrivateKey`. ECDSA can be used for authentication and signing, while ECDH is used for key agreement.

Diffie-Hellman key agreement is usually performed without static key pairs (the E in ECDHE and DHE in the SSL/TLS ciphersuites stands for ephemeral). So there should be no reason to serialize / store private keys for key agreement.

In a sense you do need to think ahead and question yourself if you need serialization at all. You shouldn't serialize keys - especially private keys - if serialization isn't needed. Instead you could just pass on the object handle.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized my question is quite wrong - The intent is to create a secret random "identity" on a trusted device and encrypt it with a public key to be transferred safely. So the keys are persistent at least per device revision. EC would be preferred over RSA because of the lesser performance requirements on the device.  I now figured that ECDH is "just" key agreement, but the libraries I checked offer ECDH(E) and ECDSA for signing  - (default) EC public key encryption seems to be ECIES, but none of the libs I checked offer it (under that name).

Comment: @peterchen For ECIES it **does** seem required to save the DH private key of the receiver (if just within a function of the library). However, a search for Botan and ECIES did return zero results for me as well (before you wrote your comment). You could possibly check out ElGamal encryption, but note that RSA encryption - which uses the RSA public key - is *relatively efficient*, it's the RSA decryption (and key generation of course) that takes loads of time.